# How to overlay single data points on bar graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a bar graph with means of 9 data points. I want to plot the bar graph with individual data points overlaid on the bar. Here is the code to generate the bar graph. I want to overlay each bar with the individual data points whose average is y. Any suggestions for how to do this would be helpful. Thank you!

```
x_num = [1:4];
x = categorical({'High PU-High RU','High PU-Low RU', 'Low PU-High RU', 'Low PU-Low RU'});
y = [0.557954545, 0.671394799, 0.543181818, 0.660227273];
figure
bar(x,y,0.4)
title('Economic Performance')
xlabel('Conditions')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `hold on` and `plot` the additional points

```
% Generate some data
x = 1:4;
y = rand(9,4);   % note: 4 columns, N rows
ymean = mean(y); % mean of each column for bar

figure();
hold on; % plot multiple things without clearing the axes
bar( x, ymean, 0.4 ); % bar of the means
plot( x, y, 'ok' );   % scatter of the data. 'o' for marker, 'k' for black
hold off
```

There are loads of options for the `plot` styling, using `'o'`, `'x'` or `'.'` as a marker type will make it a scatter rather than a line which is what you want here, other than that you can go crazy with sizing/color/linewidth etc, see the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#namevaluepairarguments).